# LG Ultrawide Screen Split Software on MacOS

Tags: mac, display, lg-monitor

Is this software just a piece of window management software? For example on MacOS if I use LG's Screen Split to arrange windows and I place a MacOS App into Apple's FullScreen implementation (not maximized) will it only Fullscreen into the allocated window space or are the window partitions more like Divvy(http://mizage.com/divvy/) and it's still one full display when entering full screen?

I'm shopping for a new monitor and an ultra wide monitor seems appealing to me if I can run apps in Fullscreen/workspaces split up around the single display.

I am assuming though this is not what Screen Split does and it's simply a window layout manager.

I guess another way to put it, under Screen Split, does the OS recognize the splits as independent monitors?

Comment: did you settle on a monitor? Ultrawide or dual monitor? I am too in the same boat. Currently, I use [Magnet](http://magnet.crowdcafe.com/) for managing windows on a dual monitor setup.